# In the Azure REST API, what is the difference between a management group's name and id?

Tags: azure

The Azure REST API method for [creating / updating a management group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/managementgroups/createorupdate) documents the endpoint as

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/{groupId}?api-version=2020-02-01
```

Notice the `groupId` URI parameter, described as

> Management Group ID.

For the [request body](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/managementgroups/createorupdate#request-body), the parameters include a `name` property, described as

> The name of the management group. For example, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

They then provide an [example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/managementgroups/createorupdate#putmanagementgroup) for this endpoint. There is no `name` property in the request, but the response *does* include a name property, which is the same as the `groupId` URI parameter.

When you [`GET` a management group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/managementgroups/get), you again include a `groupId` URI parameter

```
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/{groupId}?api-version=2020-02-01
```

but the [response](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/managementgroups/get#managementgroup) seems to call it a `name`.

So my question is: what's going on with this `groupId` / `name` thing? Are these entities synonymous, or is there something else happening here that I'm missing?